# Removing &submit=Search from search parameters?

Tags: search, urls

I added the search feature to my site using:

```
 <?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

I notice on the search page, after ?s=value, there is also &submit=Search

Is there a way to remove this through functions.php or would this be an .htaccess fix? Also, is there any use for having &submit=Search at the end of the URL?

Thanks

Comment: The button has probably a `name="Submit"` attribute. Have you tried to remove that name?

Comment: Do you have search form template in your theme? Could you show it’s contents?